# How to populate a pandas df based on conditions from another df?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-filtering

I have 2 tables in consideration:

Table 1:

| Country | Age | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25 | 7 |
| B | 45 | 8 |

Table 2:

| Age Band From | Age Band To | Country A | Country B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 |  |  |
| 40 | 50 |  |  |

The output I want to have:

| Age Band From | Age Band To | Country A | Country B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 | 7 | NaN |
| 40 | 50 | NaN | 8 |

Here's what I tried:

```
for index,row in table2.iterrows():
    table2.loc[index,'Country A'] = table1[(table1['Country']=='A')&
                                           (table1['Age']>=row[0])&
                                           (table1['Age']<=row[1])]['Marks'].values[0]
```

But this gives the following error:
`index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

I think I've probably guessed where the error occurs:
Whenever the compiler encounters a Age Band from Table2 for which a corresponding Age doesn't exist in Table1.

Any help on this problem is much appreciated! Thank You in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no efficient builtin solution in pandas to perform this operation in a generic way. A cross-merge will work on small dataframes but will have poor to terrible efficiency on large datasets. In fact as it has a quadratic complexity, this will even crash python for anything above a few thousand rows.

A robust option is to [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) then perform a [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) using [`pyjanitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = (table2[['Age Band From', 'Age Band To']]
       .conditional_join(table1.pivot(index='Age', columns='Country', values='Marks')
                               .add_prefix('Country ').reset_index(),
                         ('Age Band From', 'Age', '<='),
                         ('Age Band To', 'Age', '>='),
                         how='left'
                        )
      )
```

Output:

```
   Age Band From  Age Band To  Age  Country A  Country B
0             20           30   25        7.0        NaN
1             40           50   45        NaN        8.0
```

##### Comparison of efficiencies

Using a length `N` for both tables with random data (and deduplication):

[image]

Alternatively, if you only have a one to one mapping (i.e. no overlapping intervals, only one match in table1 per row of table2), you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for a pure pandas solution:

```
tmp = (table1.pivot(index='Age', columns='Country', values='Marks')
             .add_prefix('Country ').reset_index()
             .sort_values(by='Age')
      )

         # merge on left boundary
out = (pd.merge_asof(table2[['Age Band From', 'Age Band To']].reset_index()
                     .sort_values(by='Age Band From'),
                     tmp, direction='forward',
                     left_on='Age Band From', right_on='Age')
         .set_index('index').reindex(table2.index)
         # hide based on right boundary
         .where(lambda d: d.pop('Age').le(d['Age Band To']))
         # restore Band data if needed
         .combine_first(table2)
      )
```

Output:

```
   Age Band From  Age Band To  Country A  Country B
0             20           30        7.0        NaN
1             40           50        NaN        8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with pivoted `df1` by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and filter values by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
out = (df2[['Age Band From','Age Band To']]
            .merge(df1.pivot(index='Age', columns='Country', values='Marks')
                       .add_prefix('Country ').reset_index(), how='cross'))

out = out[out['Age'].between(out['Age Band From'], out['Age Band To'])]
print (out)
   Age Band From  Age Band To  Age  Country A  Country B
0             20           30   25        7.0        NaN
3             40           50   45        NaN        8.0
```

For more general solution is add [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (df2)
   Age Band From  Age Band To  Country A  Country B
0             20           30        NaN        NaN
1              4            5        NaN        NaN
2             20           35        NaN        NaN
3             40           50        NaN        NaN

cols = ['Age Band From','Age Band To']

out = (df2.reset_index()[cols + ['index']]
            .merge(df1.pivot(index='Age', columns='Country', values='Marks')
                       .add_prefix('Country ').reset_index(), how='cross'))

out = df2[cols].join(out[out['Age'].between(out['Age Band From'], out['Age Band To'])]
                       .set_index('index').rename_axis(None).filter(like='Country'))
print (out)
   Age Band From  Age Band To  Country A  Country B
0             20           30        7.0        NaN
1              4            5        NaN        NaN
2             20           35        7.0        NaN
3             40           50        NaN        8.0
```